# Is it necessary to polish Glassy Carbon Electrode using alumina slurry and diamond slurry? Can I use it without polishing it?

Tags: sensors

I wanted to use glassy carbon electrodes for my research study. But it is necessary to polish it before use?

Comment: What use? Test both conditions then you will know.